# Why is an external template redeclared as a "different kind of entity"?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, linkage

So I'm trying to share a templated global variable between translational units.

There is a common strategy to do this for functions where you have one header declaring/implementing the template and second C++ file that explicitly enumerates all arguments to actually generate the code for the linker.

The original version looks like

```
template<typename T>
struct PoolType
{
    void do_something()
    {

    }
};

template <class T>  PoolType<T> pool;

int main ()
{
    pool<int>.do_something(); 
    pool<float>.do_something();// can make other types 
}
```

I'm getting some strange error when extending this approach to templated structures. Does anybody know what the error means and which kind of entity is "declared"?

```
template<typename T>
struct PoolType
{
    void do_something()
    {

    }
};

template <class T>  extern PoolType<int> pool; //Suppoedly can live in another TU
//In some other file
PoolType<int> pool;

// template <class T>  PoolType<int> pool; //works fine but limited to one TU
int main ()
{
    pool<int>.do_something(); 
}
```

gcc

```
 error: 'PoolType<int> pool' redeclared as different kind of entity
```

clang

```
error: redefinition of 'pool' as different kind of symbol
```

on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vY9WT9vPK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of the two things.

1. Make `pool` a normal variable.

   ```
   extern PoolType<int> pool;
   // in some other file
   PoolType<int> pool;
   // in main
   pool.do_something();
   ```
2. Make `pool` a variable template.

   ```
   template <class T> extern PoolType<T> pool;
   // in some other file
   template <> PoolType<int> pool<int>;
   // in main
   pool<int>.do_something();
   ```

Comment: Cool, `template <> PoolType<int> pool<int>;` seems to be what I need, but can you maybe explain why you need two `<int>` tags?

Comment: There is an object named `pool<int>`, its type is `PoolType<int>`.

Comment: Ah I see, so maybe it needs one more level of indirection, so that the object is externed: https://godbolt.org/z/bxnsxjfos

Comment: You also need to **declare** your explicit specialization in `main`’s translation unit (perhaps in the same header as the template is declared), although in practice it often works anyway.  But why not use an explicit **instantiation** anyway?

Comment: @DavisHerring Do you mean the `class T` needs to be complete?

Comment: @Mikhail: No: just that it’s good to declare your special template definitions in the template’s header.  For explicit instantiations, it merely documents intent and suppresses a warning from (at the moment) Clang, but for explicit specializations it’s formally required by the standard.